# Fanfic where Harry Potter is Merlin's heir

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a fanfic where Harry is Merlin's heir, Snape is Ravenclaw's heir, and I believe Neville is Griffindor's heir. I can't remember who is Hufflepuff's heir. Harry and Lucius Malfoy are together and they live in a secret chamber in Hogwarts. Specifically, in one chapter they are getting interviewed and that's when they find out who is who's heir. They find out on this family tree that you can trace very far back. I also believe that Harry is pregnant.